# Dropping rows from a pandas dataframe on the basis of values in two columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe 'df':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,3],'b':[1,3,4],'c':[4,1,2]})
```

Now I want to drop such rows such that that row has 0 value for column'a' and non zero value for column 'b'. How can I do that?

I tried this, `df = df[df['a'] == 0 and df['b'] != 0]`, but got error.

Answer (score 1):

For combining conditions in pandas you need to use the bitwise `&` operator. e.g:

```py
condtion_a = df.a == 0
condtion_b = df.b != 0
condition = condtion_a & condtion_b
df = df[condition]
```

Or in a one liner:

```py
df = df[(df.a == 0) & (df.b != 0)]
```

**Bonus**: here is a [nice explanation](https://towardsdatascience.com/bitwise-operators-and-chaining-comparisons-in-pandas-d3a559487525)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to use `&` instead of `and` when chaining conditions inside a Pandas `.loc`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,3],'b':[1,3,4],'c':[4,1,2]})

df = df[(df['a'] == 0) & (df['b'] != 0)]
```

Result:

```
    a   b   c
0   0   1   4
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [0, 2, 3],
        'b': [1, 3, 4],
        'c': [4, 1, 2]
    }
)     

# take any rows which are having 0 in any columns   
df = df[(df['a'] == 0) | (df['b'] == 0)]
```

Comment: Explain your code please. Code only is not an answer.